# Apply changes to an existing commit without interactive rebasing

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rebase

Sometimes (very often) I make a change on my code base which I want to be part of a specific (not yet published) commit.

Usually I `stash` my changes, `rebase -i ID^` to that commit `stash pop` and `--amend` those changes and `rebase --continue`.

Problems emerge when there are more modifications than the one I want to `commit --amend` - I would first have to get rid of those e.g. by creating a temporary commit..

Is there a way to do all this in one (non-interactive) step? Something like

```
git commit --amend --rebase ID [file1, file2, ..]
```

Or is there a really good reason for all this?

Comment: Not exactly the answer (does not get rid of `rebase -i`). but might be useful, have you had a look at `commit --fixup` and `commit --squash`? It's a convenient way to do just this and have git prepare (reorder and define) its interactive todo list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that no git command would let you do that because git works by difference and can't change history of commit ID^^ without affecting ID^. That is why you can only amend last commit you made.

My suggestion is to use the `--fixup` option that let you create a commit in order to patch an old one:

```
git commit --fixup=oldCommitHash
```

And then with just this command:

```
git rebase branchDesired -i --autosquash
```

Git will reorder the commit to match original and fixup and then squash them together in the rebased branch.

It's two commands instead of one but it's a nice way to control the correctness of the rebase.